# How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core Preflight

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

I’m working with ASP.NET Core. Created the API Controller to handle Create, Get, Delete etc.  I want to be able to call he APIs from Angualr2 and finally Nativescript as an APP. Set the Cors in ConfigureServices of startup as follows:

```
 #region Cors
        //allows Cors for API 
        //NB: must procede any endpoints
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials()
                   .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2520))
                   .Build();
        }));
        // Apply as default to all controllers. API etc
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll"));
        });
        #endregion
```

Then referenced posy in the controller and actions:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/recipes")]
[EnableCors("AllowAll")]
```

and also

```
// DELETE: api/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRecipe([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Recipe.Models.Recipe recipe = await _context.Recipe.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.RecipeID == id);
        if (recipe == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Recipe.Remove(recipe);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(recipe);
    }
```

Everything works save for delete method. I get 405 method not allowed. This however works if hosting server and client are on the same domain (i.e. Localhost testing). The issue as I understand it is the preflight checks. What am I missing. Please note this is .Net Core and different from prev. versions of asp.net where u can simply create in web.config. Which incidentally I tried creating double entries in header

Comment: Have you enabled Windows authentication? Then anonymous preflight will fail with 401. Read IIS log files carefully to analyze first.

Comment: Its a hosted website. The return code is 405 not 401. But thanks anyway